# multiply column by exponent in another column

Tags: r, apply

A number is in one column, an exponent, k, m, b, ... in another column. I'm trying to do the product. I'm open to a better way of doing this. The problem is in the function. It works when I put in a single value, but not when it is given a list.

```
exp <- function(val, exp){
     switch(exp, k=1000 * val, K=1000*val, m = 1000000 * val, M=1000000 * val,
            b=1000000000 * val, B=1000000000*val, 0)
 } 
dat <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), val=c(3,4,0), exp=c('k','M',''))
dat
#  x val exp
#1 1   3   k
#2 2   4   M
#3 3   0    
apply(dat[,c('val','exp')], 1, function(x) exp(x['val'], x['exp']))

#Error in 1000 * val : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using `apply` here:

```
dat$val1 <- exp_list[dat$exp]
> dat
  x val exp  val1
1 1   3   k 1e+03
2 2   4   M 1e+06
3 3   0     1e+03
> with(dat,val * val1)
[1] 3e+03 4e+06 0e+00
```

The thing to remember is that if your 2d data structure is a data frame, `apply` is almost always the wrong choice. Note that `?apply` says that the first thing it does is convert the data frame to a matrix. If you have mixed data types, they will all be coerced, in this case to character.

A simple vectorized solution is almost always preferable.